# How to check all records in Select dialog box?

Tags: sapui5

I have a Select dialog box in xml file. I want a checkbox, which provides `"SELECT ALL`"/"`DESELECT ALL`" functionality. I cannot see any property for Select dialog box for this. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Related enhancement request: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2167

Comment: Similar request https://stackoverflow.com/q/54436888/5846045